# ShareLaTeX fails to compile quotes

Tags: symbols, babel, sharelatex

The following document is compiled incorrectly in ShareLaTeX but works perfectly in my LaTeX installation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
[ \textquotedbl a \textquotedbl, "b", "c" ]
\end{document}
```

ShareLaTeX produces "a", "b"c".

Bug of ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Probably you have to write `"{},` instead of `",`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it's a bug in your TeX installation, because `"` is a shorthand prefix in Russian `babel`, the shorthand `",` meaning a non breakable thin space.

The shorthands are

- `` "` `` for the opening low quotes: „
- `"'` for the opening high quotes: “
- `"<` for the opening guillemets: «
- `""` for a breakable zero space
- `"~` for a hyphen not allowing a line break after it
- `"=` for a hyphen allowing a line break after it and hyphenation of the following composite word chunk
- `"|` for a discretionary hyphen, allowing hyphenation after it
- `",` for a thin space that can't be used for a line break (and eats spaces after  it (used for the space between initials)
- `"-` is the same as `"=`, but `"---`, `"--*` and `"--~` give three different varieties of dashes: a normal em-dash, the dash used between compound names and the dash for direct speech respectively.

Thus the expected output is what you get in ShareLaTeX; getting a double straight quote followed by a comma is *not* what should result. The shorthand `",` has been introduced in version 1.1f of `babel-russian`, dated 1998-06-26, according to the source `.dtx` file.